# How to implement a layer blur in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, figma

In figma, there's an effect you can apply to a view called a layer blur.

[image: layer blur effect in figma]

I cannot figure out how to replicate this sort of effect as its own view in Swift.

For example, say I want to add a view that goes under a button with a layer effect as so:

[image: button with layer blur view underneath]

I have tried exporting the blur view from figma and using it as an image in code, but it just ends up like this:

[image: incorrect layer blur render on ios simulator]

These are the settings for the layer blur view I want to implement:

[image: layer blur settings in figma]

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSUWS.png)You can add a shadow to your Button(View) for that purpose

```
view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
view.layer.shadowRadius = 20
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
view.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
```

shadowOpacity: sets the transparency, where 0 will be without shadow, and 1 is the strongest.
shadowRadius: sets how wide the shadow is.
shadowOffset: sets the distance between the view and shadow.

Comment: Issue is that this current version of drop shadow doesn't allow for a standalone view to be added.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding you, would you explain more??

Comment: This answer modifies the layer, but doesn't create a new view

Comment: UIButton itself is a subView of UIControle, which is a subView of UIView. UIButton has all the properties I mentioned as does UIView. We can say UIButton is a UIView modified to execute a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can add drop shadow to a button this way.
Add an extension of UIView Like this.

```
extension UIView{
   func dropShadow() {
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.16
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
    layer.shadowRadius = 3
    }
}
```

Add drop shadow to your button by adding this line.

```
yourButton.dropShadow()
```